# If, on the Maple Wolf's 3rd day without killing, a Succubus redirects a MW's attack into a successful kill on a different target, will the MW die?

Tags: werewolv.es

Or will that count as a kill for purposes of feeding him, so that he can go another three days without killing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maple wolf will die the following night, just as if they never killed on the 3rd night.